# Mutation undetected if list is lower than 8

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, mutation-testing

Recently I started doing some C#, coming from PHP.
My way of playing with the language and learn is to do some TDD.
So i grabbed some RFC spec and wrote some tests ([RFC spec here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4122)).

I'm using NUnit right now, and Stryker to check tests quality.

Here's the situation: I have an abstract Uuid class, which has a constructor taking the version, timestamp bytes, clock-sequence bytes and node bytes.
As the RFC determines their size, I wrote some test:

```
[Test]
public void Expects8TimestampBytes()
{
    // given an invalid count of timestamp bytes
    var timestampBytes = new List<byte>
    {
        0x00,
    };

    // when trying to create an Uuid from it
    TestDelegate instanciation = () => ConcreteUuid.Constructor2(timestamp: timestampBytes);

    // then an exception should be thrown
    Assert.That(instanciation, Throws.ArgumentException);
}
```

[Full test class is available here](https://github.com/adrien-cuisse/cs-tdd/blob/master/Domain.Tests/src/ValueObject/Identity/Uuid/Uuid.Tests.cs)

The test is green, the exception is thrown:

```
protected Uuid(int version, List<byte> timestamp, List<byte> clockSequence, List<byte> node)
{
    if (timestamp.Count != 8)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"Timestamp bytes count must be 8, got {timestamp.Count}");
    }
    // more code ...
}
```

[Full class is available here](https://github.com/adrien-cuisse/cs-tdd/blob/master/Domain/src/ValueObject/Identity/Uuid/Uuid.cs)

Tests with NUnit report everyting is fine, but a mutation with Stryker survives and the condition is shown as red,
while mutants on clockSequence.Count and node.Count are green.
[image: Mutation report]

The problem seems to come from the value 8, maybe because of allocated items (which wouldn't make sense since .Count has nothind to do with .Capacity), a TrimExcess() didn't solve the problem.
The way to kill the mutation is to set timestampBytes as a List of 9+, lesser than 8 makes the mutation survive, and I don't understand why node and clock-sequence have their mutations killed with size lesser than 8 (tried reordering the conditions).

Is that something special about the number 8 ?

Comment: Well no, I don't think there is anything specific about number 8 - unless you're in China :) Have you tried to actually run the tests for this mutation? Does anything fail then?

Comment: This test all alone is Green, and the mutation is red, whereas clock-sequence and node make the mutation go green. Whatever the problem is, it only affects the timestamp list, whatever the position of the condition is.

Comment: So if you change your code to `timestamp.Count == 8` and run the tests, that test is still green?

Comment: That's exactly what happens, when me or Stryker change the condition to (timestamp.Count == 8), test still pass, so mutant isn't killed.
I can kill the mutant by:
- sending more than 8 bytes in the timestamp (anything below 8 has no effect),
- making HasRfcCompliantRepresentation() use Constructor2,
- remove exceptions from the class and make constructors take individual bytes (17 arguments, but no error case possible).

But the "why more than 8" question still remains.

Comment: Oh I see. Well at least it means it's not a Stryker problem. So debugging experience is the same? You have 8 bytes in the test, you debug it through and then the condition `timestamp.Count == 8` evaluates false?

Comment: I don't know for debugging, I don't have Visual Studio, i'm on ArchLinux and using VSCode, I'm not aware of a debugger extension (just had a look to check).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235432/discussion-between-psfinaki-and-ar7core).